# How to limit react-redux connect update re-renders to specific state branches?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, rendering

I have an action and reducer that updates a global counter. This action is fired on a rapid interval. The reducer returns a new copy of the state for each action. The reducer looks like:

```
import { handleActions } from 'redux-actions';
import { sceneTick } from './actions';

export default (state, action) => handleActions({
  [sceneTick]: (state, action) => {
    return {
      ...state,
      loop: action.payload,
    }
  },
```

I am using `react-redux`'s `connect` method on various React components. Not all the components care about this loop counter. Because I am returning a new state in the reducer on each tick, all components subscribed with `connect` get their `mapDispatchToProps` executed which causes unnecessary React render calls.

One of these componets looks like:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => {
  return {
    viewport: state.viewport,
    assets: state.assets,
  };
};


export default connect(mapStateToProps, {})(Component)
```

Even though this component has no dependency on `state.loop` it gets triggered to re-render. This causes re-rendering, over rendering, multiple rendering, unnecessary rendering, performance issues and unexpected behavior in components that need not re-render.

**Update**
I should also maybe add that I am **not** using `combineReducers` here and all reducers are applied to the full state. Not sure if relevant.

Comment: Performance issues and unexpected behavior? Can you show me where you found this information? Because I can't say I agree. DOM comparisons are very fast. It's new renders that are slow.

Comment: @Andrew The performance issues I cited **are new renders** the unexpected behaviors are from components with local state that gets reset on an unexpected re-render

Comment: When I say new renders, I mean actual changes to the component. I'm assuming you know what the virtual/shadow DOM is and how React decides what should be rerendered. Again, if I'm wrong, I'd very much like to read up on it, because this is supposed to be one of the greatest strengths of React

Comment: ok not virtual DOM performance issues but the repeated execution of selector functions, derived data functions, and allocations causing GC hits that might live within `mapDispatchToProps` functions which are being repeatedly called.  Yes I know they can be memoized

Comment: What you just described was not your original question. Redux is an opinionated flux implementation. It is hard to change. To answer your original question, it is not possible and React does a very good job when it comes to performance. Again, if I am wrong, I would be very interested in the resources you discovered this information from.

Comment: @Andrew for semantics sake What do you call it when a components render method is again called and its children components render methods are called, if not a `re-render`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162138/discussion-between-andrew-and-kevzettler).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Redux `connect` accepts a `areStatesEqual` function option that can be used to narrow down equality checks to specific state branches.

```
export default connect(
  {},
  {},
  null,
  {
    areStatesEqual: (next, prev) => {
      return (
        prev.branch === next.branch
      );
    }
  }
)(Component);
```

Comment: i do wonder how many people have used reselect when instead this approach could have been used. +1

Answer (score 6):

According to Redux implementation, `connect` is pure and hence does a shallow comparison of the props that it needs to provide to the component i.e it implements a `shouldComponentUpdate` method in its implementation and doesn't trigger a re-render for the connected component if the data returned from `mapStateToProps` doesn't change.

It is important for Redux to monitor the state change for every change because then only it can take a decision whether to update or not.

Since a Pure component does a shallow comparison of state and props, you should make sure that your states are not highly nested

Comment: I have not been able to reproduce this behavior. Should I not be returning a new object form mapStateToProps? wouldn't that invalidate the shallow comparison?

Comment: It may be a problem with your selector which returns a new object everytime, and that will violate the shallow comparison

Answer (score 0):

If it is a performance issue due to redux, use react `shouldComponentUpdate` method.

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate

---

Update: CombineReducers would make a difference. Try changing

```
return {
   ...state,
   loop: action.payload,
}
```

to

```
state.loop = ...action.payload;
return state;
```

---

If you don't want to mutate the state, you should use combineReducer with loop as its own reducer. Since you weren't using combineReducers, I turned the state into the rootReducer. Its similar to what the redux author does with combineReducers ([video](https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-implementing-combinereducers-from-scratch)) with the exception that the nextState was created within the combineReducer.

Comment: This method requires `shouldComponentUpdate` instrumentation in every component that is not concerned with the state branch being updated which is many and a large effort.

Comment: You can't stop rerenders using `shouldComponentUpdate`. That's just a lifecycle event.

Comment: Connect is very efficient. It won't rerender on state.loop if its not used within the component. Most likely another Reducer is updating unexpectantly. Redux dev tools are helpful in this situation.

Comment: @Andrew ShouldComponentUpdate doesn't stop re-renderings but it can reduce them if its due to incoming changes in props like redux state changes.

Comment: @SILENT I added an update to the OP about `combineReducers` not sure if relevant here.

Comment: @SILENT I believe you are correct, but I think you would have to be writing your code in a way that goes against re-render checks, like the constant use of `setState`

Comment: @kevzettler CombineReducers does make a difference. See if my update helps.

Comment: @Andrew Changed my wording to be more precise. I don't think you can stop setState re-rendering. However, setState is async and designed to handle numerous updates.

Comment: @SILENT the update to the mutation `state.loop =` did Indeed fix the unnecessary renders. Unfortunately, this now breaks other functionality of my project. Additionally, my understanding is this is not a redux best practice and it is encouraged to do full immutable updates to the state.

Comment: @kevzettler Is loop an object?

Comment: @kevzettler It is mutating the state. I updated my answer with the reason. If you don't want to mutate the state yet keep performance, use combineReducer.