# How Immutable.js knows when not to render a component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, immutable.js

I was curious about how Immutable.js really works so I tried to make a simple app which would demonstrate it.
I build an app (https://github.com/annamatveev/Waffle) which has two containers that are basically a two independent group of squares. Each time a square is clicked, the color of the squares changes to white.

I wanted to implemnent smart rendering so each time a square is clicked and it changes its color only that one clicked square will be re-rendered.

The best I was able to acheive is implementing shouldComponentUpdate with Immutable.js (I was suprised to find out the default behavior with Immutable.js was rendering all squares in both containers), and I separated both grid containers so that each connects to the store separetly - that prevented each change in a container to effect the other from rendering (even without Immutable.js)

I'm not sure I got it all right because almost every article out there implies that Immutable.js handles the smart rendering by itself, but I couldn't figure out how it's done.

So:

1. Does Immutable.js handles the smart rendering by itself or there is a need to implement shouldComponentUpdate each time I want to prevent unnecessary rendering?
2. I saw a lot of examples which use reselect along with Immutable.js. Does it function like a basic cache for querying the store or there is more to that? I though maybe this will solve the problem to the re-rendering but could figure out how.

Comment: Its not Immutable.js that handles smart rendering, its possible that you are using a React.PureComponent which implements shouldComponentUpdate with shallow comparison of state/props

Comment: No, I'm extending Component not PureComponent...

Comment: As you have mentioned, it happens because connect from redux is a PureComponent, check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48017252/limit-connect-update-re-renders-to-the-props-used-by-component-in-redux/48018360#48018360