# Redux state / subcomponent render triggers in react?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a react component called `contacts` and subcomponents called 'comments' and 'card'. All three are connected to the `contactReducer`

If I wrote a reducer for contacts as follows:

```
const reducer = ( state = null, action = null ) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case GET_CONTACT:
            return [
                ...state, 
                contact: action.payload
            ]
        case GET_CARD:
            return [
                ...state, 
                card: action.payload
            ]
        case GET_COMMENTS:
            return [
                ...state, 
                comments: [...action.payload]
            ]
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
export default reducer;
```

**1.a)** 
Does the parent component render each time the subcomponent receives updated props because they are all connected to the `contactReducer`?

**1.b)**
If I'm going about this the wrong way how would you recommend it be handled?

**2)** 
after each action has update the `contactReducer` once do I end up with the following object or am I way off?

```
contactsReducer = {
    contact : {someData},
    card    : {someData},
    comments: [someData, someData, ...]
}
```

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48017252/how-to-limit-react-redux-connect-update-re-renders-to-specific-state-branches/48018360#48018360 for the first point, secondly, your contactsReducer will be how you mention it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any object that receives a new object as a prop or if their state changes will re-render in accordance with react's diffing algorithm.  That is assuming you don't overwrite the `componentShouldUpdate` method.

1a - the parent will receive the new state from the reducer and re-render anything that should change.

1b / 2 - In your current implementation, you will have a single array with a mix of objects with keys varying from `contact, card, and comments`. You should look into redux's functionality `combineReducers` and create a reducer for each of those keys. I would strongly recommend you watch a video series on Redux to see the design patterns, it will go a long way - [video](https://egghead.io/courses/getting-started-with-redux)

Comment: Ok, so essentially the render only occurs if the prop value for a specific component has changed and it only updates that specific component.

Comment: yes, and if the component has children the changes will trickle down as well